# C# MVVM Assign decimal properyy throws error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I'm setting the following decimal values in a WinUI 3.0 app:

```
CustomFee = _selectedItem.CustomFee;
ReclaimThreshold = _selectedItem.ReclaimThreshold;
```

I'll get the following error on either one of these settings. Its not consistant which one:

*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Setting to zero works fine:

```
CustomFee = 0m;
ReclaimThreshold = 0m;
```

Here is the get/set for the properties:

```
private decimal _customFee;
public decimal CustomFee
{
    get => _customFee;
    set =>  SetProperty(ref _customFee, value);
}

private decimal _reclaim;
public decimal Reclaim
{
    get => _reclaim;
    set => SetProperty(ref _reclaim, value);
}
```

If I were to do this in the get

```
set =>  _customFee = value;
```

no error is not thrown but that doesn't get with what I want in this MVVM app.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Carl

Comment: What is `SetProperty`? Come from a base class? from a library?

Comment: Its found here: CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** this way.

**YourViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace Mvvm;

// This class needs to be "partial" for the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.
public partial class YourViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm will auto-generate an UI-interactive 
    // "CustomFee" property for you.
    private double _customFee;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace Mvvm;
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public YourViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="Mvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CustomFee, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```